# how to escape a shell command in bash script written by another bash script

Tags: bash, shell, escaping, heredoc

Can anybody show me how to escape a shell command in bash script written by another bash script ?

For example my script looks like:

```sh
sudo sh -c "echo \"if who | grep tty | grep \`whoami\` > /dev/null\"        > test.sh"  
sudo sh -c "echo \"then\"                                                  >> test.sh"
sudo sh -c "echo \"    echo ' log in '\"                                       >> test.sh"
sudo sh -c "echo \"else\"                                                  >> test.sh"
sudo sh -c "echo \"    exit\"                                              >> test.sh"
sudo sh -c "echo \"fi\"                                                    >> test.sh"
```

I want that the script test.sh contains

```
if who | grep tty | grep `whoami`> /dev/null
then
    echo 'user  is log in '
else
    exit
fi
```

Actually the command whoami is replaced by root.

Solution:

```
sudo tee /usr/local/bin/test.sh  << 'EOF'
if who | grep tty | grep `whoami`> /dev/null
then
    echo 'user  is log in '
else
    exit
fi
EOF
```

Comment: I am not getting it why not write simply commands in script? Why you ae using `sh -c` thing? Please add more details in your post as it is not clear.

Comment: not sure to understand your question. I have a master script that generates other scripts. My test.sh script need to be generated on the fly on specific computer by the main script.

Comment: But why do you want echo to run as a different user?

Comment: Because main script can be executed by normal user and sudo is used when generated script need to be placed in /usr/local/bin . My example has been simplified but my test.sh script need to be located in /usr/local/bin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complex quotes are most easily handled with a heredoc:

```
cat > test.sh << 'EOF'
if who | grep tty | grep `whoami`> /dev/null
then
    echo 'user  is log in '
else
    exit
fi
EOF
```

Comment: thanks for the idea. Since I do not suceed to use 'sudo' with 'cat', I use 'tee' instead